# a mass of clouds is / a mass of clouds are

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, noun-phrases

I was given a sentence:

> Venus is covered in a mass of clouds which **is** thought to be a couple of miles thicker.

The correct answer to which was:

> Venus is covered in a mass of clouds which **are** thought to be a couple of miles thicker.

But to me, the first one sounds more natural.

Does the same rule as in:

> "-A number of people are
> -The number of people is"

apply here?

Comment: a couple of miles thick, **not** thicker.

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle difference in meaning between the sentences.  In the first (which is) the relative clause modifies the noun "mass". The mass is thicker.

In the second the relative clause modifies the noun "clouds". The clouds are thicker.

Compare:

> A herd of cows, which is splitting into two parts.

> A herd of cows, which are chewing the grass.

In the first one the clause modifies "herd"  (it is unlikely that the individual cows are splitting).  In the second the clause modifies "cows" as a herd doesn't chew, only the individual cows have mouths to chew.

In your example it the "mass is thicker" and "the clouds are thicker" probably mean the same thing. So it doesn't matter, and both is and are can be correct.

I suppose the "Number of" example is similar.  You can say

> A number of people are crossing the bridge.

> A number of people is prime.

In the first case (which is more common) you are talking about the people.  In the second you are talking about the number.

Comment: Upvoted and agreed except to quibble that "which is" is slightly better because it's the overall mass of clouds which is thought to be a couple of miles thick, not any of the clouds that make up the mass.